# Rounding float in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rounding

I'm having problems rounding.  I have a float, which I want to round to the hundredth of a decimal.  However, I can only use `.round` which basically turns it into an int, meaning `2.34.round # => 2.`  Is there a simple effect way to do something like `2.3465 # => 2.35`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

When displaying, you can use (for example)

```
>> '%.2f' % 2.3465
=> "2.35"
```

If you want to store it rounded, you can use

```
>> (2.3465*100).round / 100.0
=> 2.35
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize sprintf would take care of rounding for me.   `sprintf '%.2f', 2.3465` also works.

Comment: value.round(2) is better than this solution

Comment: Keep in mind that `2.3000.round(2) => 2.3` and `sprintf '%.2f', 2.300 => 2.30`. In my opinion this is a flaw in round(), or it should have an option to preserve trailing zeros.

Comment: @Excalibur `2.3000.round(2)` is a number, not a string. There is no way that the number `2.3` is different from `2.30`, so there is no way to have an option to preserve trailing zeros. You could make your own class of numbers_with_significance but then we already have strings.

Comment: Note that although this *does* work for two decimal places, there's a flaw in `'%.3f' % 1.2345` (3 decimal places, not 2), however!! Same for `sprintf` as well. Beware. That will return `=> 1.234` **not** `=> 1.235` as most would expect (iow, after the 2nd decimal, sprintf rounds 5 **down** and only rounds a 6 up). That's why Kit Ho's comment above has 25+ upvotes. Safer to use, `'%.3f' % 1.2345.round(3)` so the number is properly rounded by `.round` first, then formatted (with trailing zeros, if need be).

Comment: `sprintf` rounds 0.5 to the nearest even digit.   `'%.3f' % 1.2355` and `'%.3f' % 1.2365` both give "1.236"

`.round` rounds 0.5 up

Answer (score 415):

Pass an argument to round containing the number of decimal places to round to

```
>> 2.3465.round
=> 2
>> 2.3465.round(2)
=> 2.35
>> 2.3465.round(3)
=> 2.347
```

Comment: This would seem more sensible than multiplying, rounding and dividing. +1

Comment: Hmm this method doesn't seem to be in ruby 1.8.7.  Maybe in 1.9?

Comment: @Brian. This is definitely in 1.9 and is also in rails (Which this question was tagged with)

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7's round method doesn't have this ability, adding the decimal place rounding parameter is a 1.9 ability

Comment: Note that you don't get trailing zeros with this, so `1.1.round(2)` => `1.1` not `1.10`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid rounding of the numbers that doesn't have any decimels in it ? like if it is 0 it should as 0 and not 0.0

Comment: `2.4.round(3) => 2.4`

Answer (score 12):

you can use this for rounding to a precison..

```
//to_f is for float

salary= 2921.9121
puts salary.to_f.round(2) // to 2 decimal place                   

puts salary.to_f.round() // to 3 decimal place
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a method in Float Class, I learnt this from stackoverflow:

```
class Float
    def precision(p)
        # Make sure the precision level is actually an integer and > 0
        raise ArgumentError, "#{p} is an invalid precision level. Valid ranges are integers > 0." unless p.class == Fixnum or p < 0
        # Special case for 0 precision so it returns a Fixnum and thus doesn't have a trailing .0
        return self.round if p == 0
        # Standard case  
        return (self * 10**p).round.to_f / 10**p
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also provide a negative number as an argument to the `round` method to round to the nearest multiple of 10, 100 and so on.

```
# Round to the nearest multiple of 10. 
12.3453.round(-1)       # Output: 10

# Round to the nearest multiple of 100. 
124.3453.round(-2)      # Output: 100
```

Answer (score 3):

what about `(2.3465*100).round()/100.0`?

Answer (score 2):

```
def rounding(float,precision)
    return ((float * 10**precision).round.to_f) / (10**precision)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to display it, I would use the [number_with_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) helper.
If you need it somewhere else I would use, as Steve Weet pointed, the `round` method

Comment: Note that `number_with_precision` is Rails-only method.

Answer (score 0):

For ruby 1.8.7 you could add the following to your code:

```
class Float
    alias oldround:round
    def round(precision = nil)
        if precision.nil?
            return self
        else
            return ((self * 10**precision).oldround.to_f) / (10**precision)
        end 
    end 
end
```